# how do I properly execute a program with scheme48?

Tags: linux, scheme, scheme48

I'm learning Scheme. I want to build *script-fu* filters for Gimp, so I was using *tinyscheme* to execute the scripts I made, but it seems like *tinyscheme* has a very limited set of functions, functions like `max`, `min` and `even?`, are missing. (I'd like someone to prove me wrong here :( )

Ok, actually, I just want to execute a Scheme script with scheme48. How do I do that?

for example, how do I execute the following file with *scheme48*?

```
(define (addx inNum inX)
  (if (> (* inNum inX) 999) 0
      (+ (* inNum inX) (addx inNum (+ 1 inX)))))

(display 
  (- (+ (addx 3 1) (addx 5 1)) (addx 15 1)))
```

Comment: I would imagine that you'd put it in a file, then start scheme48 with a flag that refers to the file. What operating system is this? What have you tried, and what did it do?

Comment: you might want to try drscheme it's really easy to use.

Comment: @JohnClements I think is not that simple, like using an argument and executing the script. GNU/Linux, you may want to check the question's tags. In any case, I'm asking for guidance, as a novice.

Comment: @mux Thanks, I will investigate more on that.

Comment: @mux ... though it's now called DrRacket, or simply Racket. (And is incredibly awesome.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also was not able to run a scheme-script with scheme48 successfully (and I couldn’t find a hint in the manual yet). You may alternatively use Guile (assuming, you are working on linux or something like that):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/guile -s
!#

(define (addx in-num in-x)
  (if (>  (* in-num in-x) 999)
      0
      (+ (* in-num in-x) (addx in-num (+ 1 in-x)))))

(display (- (+ (addx 3 1) (addx 5 1)) (addx 15 1)))
(newline)
```

Save it and then run:

```
$chmod u+x test.scm
./test.scm 
233168
$
```

(by the way: Please don’t format Scheme like C).

**EDIT**

According to a post of Mike Sperber on the [Scheme48 mailing list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.scheme.scheme48/2422), shebanging will not work. Explicitely invoking Scheme48 is to be done this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
scheme48 -a batch << EOF
(letrec ((fac (lambda (n)
             (if (= n 1)
                 1
                 (* n (fac (- n 1)))))))
 (fac 5))
EOF

$ ./test.scm
120
```

Comment: Yes, XD sorry about that, a C-like syntax feels more natural to me. I'm still not comfortable using the Lisp syntax. Also, thank you for the elaborate answer. Guile very nice.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't accept your answer since is not quite related to the original question. Although, thanks to you, now I'm able to run the scripts I make.

Comment: @Kira: Why was my answer not related to your question? :)

Comment: unfortunately my question is about how to execute a Scheme script with **scheme48*. Your answer provide an alternative, I'm fine with it (really), but other people might not, and they even might be force to ask the same question again.

Comment: @Kira: After some research I could find a solution addressing to your original question. I have updated my answer accordingly.